# Assigning 257 applications between two assessors each, from uneven panel number

Tags: fair-division

So I am very bad at math and have a problem I am dealing with.

I have 257 applications for a job.

Each application has to be assessed by two assessors.

The panel of assessors has five assessors.

So I need to divide the 257 applications up accordingly, assigning two assessors to each application.

How many applications should each assessor have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a total of $2\times 257=514$ **assessments** that have to be made. There are $5$ people making assessments. How many assessments does one person get?

Actually, $514$ is not divisible by $5$, but maybe it doesn't matter that one person gets one fewer assessments than the others.

Comment: Thank you - such a simple answer that I feel very dumb for asking!